# Why can’t my custom domain on Heroku be resolved?

Tags: heroku

I configured a custom domain for a small site on Heroku on Friday. It worked then, but now, it's broken. The host is `nedgros.de`. `nedgros.herokuapp.com` has address 23.21.239.236.

Is does not resolve to the right application. How can I configure the DNS to follow the Dyno dynamics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ dig  nedgros.de any
...
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nedgros.de.                    IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nedgros.de.             86301   IN      CNAME   nedgros.herokuapp.com.
```

Short answer: you *cannot* have a CNAME at the "top" of the zone, a CNAME is an alias or reference, it cannot coexist with any other data. Specifically, it cannot coexist with a NS and SOA records which are rather important for the correct operation of your domain. RFC 1912 Section 2.4.

You have not properly followed the Heroku instructions. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains , if this setup is what you want read the part on "Apex domains".

Comment: thanks... looks like a very good answer to my problem. I try to remove the Apex config. Small additional question I want to have some subdomains, like mx.nedgros.de pointing to another IP for mail. It's possible to combine?

Comment: ok, I removed the nedgros.de --> CNAME entry... still, do I also need to remove the entries for NS and SOA? I was operating the site before on a VPS

Comment: NS and SOA are essential. You seem to have just moved NS provider this morning. As the domain appears "parked", perhaps you have lost control of it, or have not yet set it up correctly?

You can add other records as required, there are still constraints on valid data, you should use one of the web-based tools to check www.dnscheck.com is straightforward (and captcha free).